# Как вместо бана выдать роль (бана)

Tags: python, discord.py

У меня создан ивент (я только начинающий и делал по гайду с ютуба бота модератора)
В котором при достижении 7 варнов из файл users.json выдается бан на сервере по причине (которую я укажу)

```
    if data[str(message.author.id)]['WARNS'] >= 7:
        await message.author.ban(reason="Вы превысили допустимое кол-во нарушений!")
```

Так вот, мне бы хотелось, чтобы выдавался не бан, а конкретная роль

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    WARN = BADWORDS + LINKS

    for i in range(0, len(WARN)):
        if WARN[i] in message.content.lower():
            await message.delete()
            with open('users.json', 'r') as file:
                data = json.load(file)
                file.close()

            with open('users.json', 'w') as file:
                data[str(message.author.id)]['WARNS'] += 1
                json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
            
            file.close()

            emb = discord.Embed(
                title="Нарушение",
                description=f"*Ранее у нарутеля было уже {data[str(message.author.id)]['WARNS'] - 1} нарушений, после 7 он будет забанен!*",
                timestamp=message.created_at
            )

            emb.add_field(name="Канал:", value=message.channel.mention, inline=True)
            emb.add_field(name="Нарушитель:", value=message.author.mention, inline=True)
            emb.add_field(name="Тип нарушения:", value="Запрещенные слова/Ссылки", inline=True)

            await get(message.guild.text_channels, id=985065582825189377).send(embed=emb)

            if data[str(message.author.id)]['WARNS'] >= 7:
                await message.author.ban(reason="Вы превысили допустимое кол-во нарушений!")

        if message.content.isupper():
            with open('users.json', 'r') as file:
                data = json.load(file)
                file.close()

            with open('users.json', 'w') as file:
                data[str(message.author.id)]["CAPS"] += 1
                json.dump(data, file, indent=4)

            if data[str(message.author.id)]["CAPS"] >= 3:
                await message.delete()
                with open ('users.json', 'w') as file:
                    data[str(message.author.id)]["CAPS"] = 0
                    data[str(message.author.id)]["WARNS"] += 1
                    
                    json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
                    file.close()


                    emb = discord.Embed(
                        title="Нарушение",
                        description=f"*Ранее у нарутеля было уже {data[str(message.author.id)]['WARNS'] - 1} нарушений, после 7 он будет забанен!*",
                        timestamp=message.created_at
                    )

                    emb.add_field(name="Канал:", value=message.channel.mention, inline=True)
                    emb.add_field(name="Нарушитель:", value=message.author.mention, inline=True)
                    emb.add_field(name="Тип нарушения:", value="КАПС", inline=True)

                    await get(message.guild.text_channels, id=985065582825189377).send(embed=emb)

                    if data[str(message.author.id)]['WARNS'] >= 7:
                        await message.author.ban(reason="Вы превысили допустимое кол-во нарушений!")

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получите объект роли

```py
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=ид роли)
```

Далее выдайте её соответствующему пользователю и отправьте сообщение с уведомлением о блокировке

```py
member.add_roles(role)
embed = discord.Embed(
    title='Блокировка',
    color=0xFF0033
)
embed.add_field(name='Причина', value=f'{member.mention}'
embed.add_field(name='Причина:', value=f'{reason}')

await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```